# Привести уравнения из системы к стандартному виду для решения методом Гаусса

Tags: c, строки, уравнения

**Дано:** строка, содержащая уравнения, разделенные '\n'.
**Необходимо:** перекинуть числа в правую часть, а все слагаемые, содержащие переменные в левую, учитывая знак.

Реализовал пока что только разделение уравнений, запихал их в массив. Теперь необходимо пройтись по каждому уравнению, определить какие из слагаемых в левой части не содержат переменных и переместить их в правую часть, учитывая знак и, наоборот, слагаемые, содержащие переменные, переместить в левую часть, также учитывая знак и запихать уже преобразованные уравнения в массив. Как бы такое реализовать?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3

char EquasionSorting(char EquasionSystem[]) {
    char Separator[10] = "\n";
    char *Equasion;
    char Equasions[N][100];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Before:\n%s", EquasionSystem);
    printf("\nAfter:\n");
    Equasion = strtok(EquasionSystem, Separator);
    while (Equasion != NULL) {
        strcpy(Equasions[i], Equasion);
        Equasion = strtok(NULL, Separator);
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char EquasionSystem[] = "-2.2x+2y=13\n5.8z-2x-3=0\n2y+4=z";
    EquasionSorting(EquasionSystem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Элементарно. `sscanf()` вам в помощь.

Comment: Также, как делили на уравнения. Теперь каждое уравнение делите на слагаемые, используя в качестве `Separator = "+-="`, а далее каждое слагаемое проверяете на буквы. Если буквы есть - слагаемое в левую часть, если в слагаемом только цифры - в правую.